# Can't create socket on Windows

Tags: c, networking, winsock, sockets

I have quite an embarrassing problem. The following code simply will not create a socket on Windows; it fails and displays the error message. Could anyone briefly explain why this might be? I'm incredibly confused and frustrated that something so simple is failing. Thank you.

```
int sock;
if( (sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0 )
{
    printf("error opening socket");
}
```

EDIT: Also, printing out strerror(errno) simply shows "No error".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to call `WSAStartup()` before any other socket functions will work on Windows (and you're supposed to call `WSACleanup()` when you're done).

Comment: Thank you...somehow I have been getting winsock to work all this time without using that function. Very strange.

Comment: You are probably usually using some other component that needs to use sockets and which is doing the startup for you...

Answer (score 6):

Here look at the working example below:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

int _cdecl main(){
   WSADATA Data;
   int socket; // or you can use SOCKET socket
   WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &Data); // 2.2 version
   socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
   if(udep_socket<0){
        printf("Error Creating Socket");
   }else{
        printf("Successfully Created Socket");
   }
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

The following sources are useful for understanding:

- [Initializing Winsock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/initializing-winsock)
- [Getting Started with Winsock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/getting-started-with-winsock)

Answer (score 3):

[Jerry Coffin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004307/cant-create-socket-on-windows/2004318#2004318) is right about `WSAStartup()` and `WSACleanup()`.

Also note that this code

```
if( (sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0 )
```

is problematic because `SOCKET`  is an unsigned type (`unsigned int`).

From `winsock.h`

```
/*
 * This is used instead of -1, since the
 * SOCKET type is unsigned.
 */
#define INVALID_SOCKET  (SOCKET)(~0)
#define SOCKET_ERROR            (-1)
```

So, IMO it's better to replace that line with

```
if( INVALID_SOCKET == (sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) )
```

even if it's not the root cause.