# what does error code "5" mean in winsock2?

Tags: c++, winsock2

I'm making a simple client-server application using winsock2 library, but I get a "5" error code when I try to open a socket, but the first error code in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2) is "6". The thing is, I don't understand what causes the program to exit.

```
int sockfd;
if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) {
    perror("socket creation failed");
    #ifdef OS_WINDOWS
    std::cerr << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
    #endif
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: Try [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) instead.  That is "ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED".  Also, that WSA error documentation shows the large jump between error number values.  I believe that is to match the same error codes in GetLastError.

Comment: You should post a [mcve].  There is no indication if you called `WSAStartup` before issuing other calls to create sockets.

Comment: well, actually I didn't call WSAStartup, let me try

Comment: That'll probably be why then :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error codes returned from [WSAGetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2) are a subset of the error codes returned by [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes).

Since `GetLastError` is a superset of all the errors returned by `WSAGetLastError`, calling `GetLastError` will yield the same error values as calling `WSAGetLastError`, plus any errors that are not Winsock-related.

A `5` return code is an `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.  Why you are getting this error is a different story.

See [the following link explaining what may cause this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004307/cant-create-socket-on-windows).